# Use OptionMenu as a Menu in Python using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, tk-toolkit, optionmenu

To increase my understanding and usability of python I have been building a text editor from scratch. What I'm trying to do now is allow the user to change the size of the font. I have this working using an OptionMenu but by using that I have to have a drop down on the interface.  What I'm trying to do is somehow put the option menu into a menu on the top bar (with file_menu = Menu(root)) and make it look like a cascade. I don't have my exact code as I'm on mobile and away from my laptop, but I've been thinking about how to do this and I can't figure it out And wasn't able to find it searching earlier. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I figured out how to do it, and I apologize for not having my original code. My original code was something like the answer posted below me, but I wanted to let the user select font sizes ranging from 8-40 so having

```
font_size.add_command(label='8', command=lambda: font_size_changer(8))
font_size.add_command(label='10', command=lambda: font_size_changer(10))
font_size.add_command(label='12', command=lambda: font_size_changer(12))
```

Just looked bad for how many I wanted. I ended up not doing the OptionMenu and IntVar() and went with a for loop like so:

```
def font_size_changer(clicked_size):
    global current_font_size
    current_font_size = clicked_size
    text.config(font=(current_font, current_font_size, style_combo))

sizes_list = [8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
font_size = Menu(menu)
font_menu.add_cascade(label="Font Size", menu=font_size)
for x in range(0, len(sizes_list)):
    font_size.add_command(label=str(sizes_list[x]), command=lambda: font_size_changer(sizes_list[x]))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I understand you were not at your computer when you asked this question however that does not change the fact that you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can understand what it is you have done so far and provide feedback based on that code. Instead of asking a question without the MCVE or without the proper context, you should instead wait until you can provide the MCVE and ask your question then.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you could use an `OptionMenu` to do this Tkinter actually has a native `Menu` object which we could use to achieve similar results much more cleanly and with less code.

This is actually not too tricky to pull off, see below for an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Lorem Ipsum", font=("Comic Sans MS", 44))
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.root)
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Small", command=lambda:self.label.config(font=("Comic Sans MS", 22)))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Medium", command=lambda:self.label.config(font=("Comic Sans MS", 44)))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Big", command=lambda:self.label.config(font=("Comic Sans MS", 66)))
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Size", menu=self.menu)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.label.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So let's break this down.

We create two `Menu` objects `menubar` and `menu`. We then store all of the commands inside of `menu`, this creates a fleshed out `Menu` object with a few entries in them.

Each command is setup to change the font size of `label`

We then add a cascade item to `menubar` selecting the predefined `menu` as our `Menu` object for the cascade.

`root.config(menu=self.menubar` is then used to "draw" the `Menu` object on our window.

This results in a cascading menu at the top of the screen where each option in the menu allows us to change the font size of a `label` object.

Comment: It'd be nice to be able to highlight which option is currently selected, which the OptionMenu provides